# How do I check gstreamer version?

Tags: versions, gstreamer

I want to know what version of gstreamer I have installed.

If it turns out that I have multiple versions I want to know which is being used.

---

**Edit:**

It turns out that things are a bit messy. There *are* multiple versions of gstreamer (mainly 0.1 and 1.0) and they're being used in parallel (they should be treated as separate) [(Source)](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-getting.html#getting-gstreamer-packages). As for the packages there's plenty of them. Here are the packages that came out from the `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer` command:

```
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0                                        1.2.4-0ubuntu1                                         amd64        Description: GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64                                    0.10.36-1.1ubuntu2                                     amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:amd64                                  0.10.13-5ubuntu1~trusty2.1                             amd64        FFmpeg plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3:amd64                             0.10.23.debian-3                                       amd64        Fluendo mp3 decoder GStreamer 0.10 plugin
ii  gstreamer0.10-gconf:amd64                                   0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for getting the sink/source information from GConf
ii  gstreamer0.10-nice:amd64                                    0.1.4-1                                                amd64        ICE library (GStreamer 0.10 plugin)
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:amd64                             0.10.23-7.2ubuntu1.1                                   amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse                        0.10.21-1ubuntu3                                       amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set (Multiverse Variant)
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:amd64                            0.10.36-1.1ubuntu2                                     amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps                             0.10.36-1.1ubuntu2                                     amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64                            0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5                                  amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64                            0.10.19-2ubuntu5                                       amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64                              0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer0.10-tools                                         0.10.36-1.2ubuntu3                                     amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer0.10-x:amd64                                       0.10.36-1.1ubuntu2                                     amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                                     1.2.4-1~ubuntu2                                        amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter                                        2.0.8-1build1                                          amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:amd64                              0.10.23.debian-3                                       amd64        Fluendo mp3 decoder GStreamer 1.0 plugin
ii  gstreamer1.0-gnonlin                                        1.2.0-1                                                amd64        non-linear editing module for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                                    1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        libav plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-nice:amd64                                     0.1.4-1                                                amd64        ICE library (GStreamer plugin)
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64                              1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:amd64                         1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        GStreamer faad plugin from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:amd64                 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        GStreamer videoparsers plugin from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64                             1.2.4-1~ubuntu2                                        amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps                              1.2.4-1~ubuntu2                                        amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64                             1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64                             1.2.3-2build1                                          amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                               1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                                          1.2.4-0ubuntu1                                         amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                                        1.2.4-1~ubuntu2                                        amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0:amd64                        0.10.23-7.2ubuntu1.1                                   amd64        GStreamer shared libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64                         1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64                       0.10.36-1.1ubuntu2                                     amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386                        0.10.36-1.1ubuntu2                                     i386         GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64                        1.2.4-1~ubuntu2                                        amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386                         1.2.4-1~ubuntu2                                        i386         GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64                        1.2.4-1~ubuntu1                                        amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64                                    0.10.36-1.2ubuntu3                                     amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamer0.10-0:i386                                     0.10.36-1.2ubuntu3                                     i386         Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                                     1.2.4-0ubuntu1                                         amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386                                      1.2.4-0ubuntu1                                         i386         Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamermm-0.10-2                                       0.10.11-0ubuntu2                                       amd64        C++ wrapper library for the multimedia library GStreamer (shared libraries)
ii  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer                       1:4.2.8-0ubuntu4                                       amd64        GStreamer backend for LibreOffice
ii  phonon-backend-gstreamer:amd64                              4:4.7.80-0ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04                          amd64        Phonon GStreamer 1.0.x backend
ii  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common:amd64                       4:4.7.80-0ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04                          amd64        Phonon GStreamer 1.0.x backend icons
ii  phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0                                 4:4.7.80-0ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04                          all          transitional package
```

Comment: Other than accepted answer you can also `gst-launch-1.0 --version`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
dpkg -l | grep gstreamer
```

to display all installed packages with `gstreamer` in the package name.

Answer (score 24):

Please try using this command, it might give you the version you're looking for:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version
```

Comment: @Thomas
I guess people can understand from simple words too. No edit was required.

Comment: the additional text wasn't needed, but the formatting for the command was helpful

Comment: One thing I like about this answer is that - while this is an Ubuntu-focused site - this method is more general and will work even on distros without `dpkg`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this command:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 --gst-version
```

[image: image of command and output in terminal]

Answer (score 0):

"gst-inspect-1.0 --gst-version" or "gst --version"